# Why should I be careful with html_safe?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

From a developer's point of view I understand that HTML safe allows you to put HTML tags/entities in a string from within the controller, and then have that string rendered as HTML in the view.

However, from a security point of view, I'm not sure I understand why it is necessary. When should I *not* use html_safe on a string? In my case this is a user editable field, but I can't imagine what type of attack this would make possible.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting

Comment: Interesting, so this suggests that I should never make a user editable field html_safe if and only if it is viewable by other users? If, for example, the field was the user's first name (which is only rendered on their dashboard) it would be okay?

Comment: If it truly was only on their page, maybe, but why bother?  Use safe practices all the time.   What if you later add an admin view that lets the admin view the site as another user?  oops.

Answer (score 1):

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html

A very clear guide about security issues, including XSS, and why you should escape user-editable content.